# Facebook API Error: "User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a Facebook app (in development mode) to generate a page access token so that my personal web app can schedule/edit/delete posts on a Facebook fan page.

I'm using the Graph Explorer to generate the token while logged in as the **admin** of the fan page.

When I use that token, I'm able to GET a list of the scheduled posts, but whenever I try to edit or delete a post, I get this error:

*"User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page."*

Here is the debug of the token:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the user does not have the necessary admin level on the page - this is something that needs to be fixed in the page settings.

Comment: I am the admin of the page. I can manually create, edit and delete scheduled posts within Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Here according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post)

**DELETING YOUR POST**

These are the permissions you need in the scope of your token.

- To delete a user's post, a user access token with **publish_actions** permission is required.
- To delete a Page's post a Page access token and publish_pages permission is required.
- To delete a User's post on Page a Page access token is required.
- To delete another User's post on a Page-owned event the user_managed_groups permission is required.

**UPDATING YOUR POST**

- A user access token with **publish_actions** permission.

SO you need **publish_actions** permission within the scope of your token.

**Update 1**

> Also check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#roles) if you have the valid page role

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm just trying to create/delete/update Page posts, so only publish_pages is required, which I already have.

Comment: I also added publish_actions to the scope, but am still getting the same error

Comment: Please update the screenshot which you get after adding publish_actions plugin,would be very helpful and can you also mention the error now which you get please? thanks.

Comment: yea i think you are right,it should have definitely worked,maybe you can try to add user access token too with publish_actions permission and also add user_managed_groups permission to it

Comment: I have tried all of those things. If you use a user token with publish_actions, it says you need a page token. I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest documentation of the facebook graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/page/feed), We can call the following endpoint to create a post on the page.
create your post by requesting the /{page-id}/feed endpoint of the selected page. You can find the delete and update endpoint here as well.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{page-id}/feed?access_token={page-access-token}

{page-id}: The id of the target page in the data list
{page-access-token}: The access_token of the target page in the data list
Request body: Post object in JSON format. Add {“message” : “your post”} to set the text. Add {“link” : “A URL”} to include an image or other media.
Header ‘Content-Type': 'application/json‘
```